# Move open tabs bar to bottom in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an option in VS Code to move this bar
[image: top bar]

to the bottom of the screen, just above console?
In JetBrains' products, for example, there is a setting for this: `Tab placement: Bottom`

In JetBrains' products:
[image: Pycharm example]

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try drag&drop feature ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Trying to drag and drop tabs does nothing in my VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### After 2 days of research I have finally come up with solution.

1. First install Customize UI.
2. Add this lines to your settings.json:

   ```
    "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
        ".editor-group-container": "display: flex !important; flex-direction: column;",
        ".editor-group-container > .title": "order: 1;"
    }
   ```

Also you can switch the tabs and breadcrumbs by using this:

```
    "customizeUI.stylesheet": { 
        ".editor-group-container > .title": "display: flex !important; flex-direction: column; order: 1;", 
        ".editor-group-container > .title > .tabs-and-actions-container": "order: 1;" 
    }
```

**Note:** there's an issue with breadcrumbs popup window, but I don't how to fix this bug.

Comment: Thank you, this works! It's a pity that this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50318 is still not implemented and we have to "hack" it like this, but this works. Are you aware of how the CSS injection should be changed to flip the places of the path bar and the tabs bar (currently tabs is at the top and path at the bottom, but I would like to have it just the other way)?

Comment: I has edited the original answer.